# SQL2Mongo connection strings

Tags: mongodb, connection-string

Has anyone tried the SQL2Mongo importer? 
I want to migrate my data from SQL server to MongoDB and i know that is a PITA to get the relations right, but i thought this tool would be a good start. However i cant get the connection strings to work, so im just wondering if someone has tried this or is it just a joke :P

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

C:\Sql2Mongo>sql2mongo "data source=sqlservername;uid=username;pwd=aaa;database=databasename;" "mongodb://localhost:27017)"

http://sql2mongo.codeplex.com/